# Regain access to unreachable Sharepoint subsites or libraries

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have a full control permission of our team's Sharepoint site (I think it's Sharepoint 2010, but could also be 2013... I can't tell). For test purpose I created a subsite within this site. I set the subsite to not inherit the parent site's permission and make myself the only user who can see and access the subsite. Later I removed myself as the user of this subsite (i.e. this subsite has no user and no admin). Now whenever I am in the main site, I still can see the link to this subsite, but I cannot access it (it says 'access denied'... I also can't delete this subsite). I would consider this a flaw that Sharepoint lets me make my subsite unreachable, but is there any away I can regain access to this subsite?

Is there perhaps any permission that is more powerful than Full Control?

p.s. this can also happen with document libraries, list, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have permission for it, make yourself Site Collection Owner. After that you can access your subsite again.

**Add or change a site collection administrator**

1. At the top level of your site collection, click Site Actions and
   then Site Settings.
2. Under Users and Permissions, click Site Collection Administrators.
3. In the Site Collection Administrators field, type or browse to find
   the name of the person you want to designate a site collection
   administrator.
4. Click OK.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not the site collection administrator and I can't make myself site collection admin. Is there any other way to regain access?

Comment: As far as I know there is no other way you can get you access back to the subsite. Ask the Site Collection Owner to give you owner permission on the subsite so you regain access.

Comment: If you can get access to Central Admin as the main farm admin I think you can assign yourself to be a site colleciton admin from there as well